# PHP Encode special characters in input web service XML

Tags: php

Users call a web service API in my PHP code but don't properly encode the input (like the & sign etc) so because of nonsense (I can't use the b* word here but you know that a developer don't care about politics or feelings, you do it right or not!) it is my problem to fix it... How can I encode the input XML before I try to parse it in PHP?

I did a string replace for the & sign but off-course there are more invalid characters in the universe that these people (the a* word) can use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more details and code its hard to say exactly what you need, but look at `urlencode()` or `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Answer (score 0):

I'm nearly totally sure that there isn't a builtin feature to do this, in php. Because the minimum that php's modules need is... a proper encoded xml file ( for libxml / libdom for instance)

An improper encoded file is hard to sanitize because you have to consider "what should be encoded" and "what should not be encoded"

you need to tokenize your input xml, then you need to examine every single piece and sanitize wrong pieces of code, for instance the character " contained inside an attribute

it is a hard work, then the better thing you can do, is fix or make fix the source xml

IMHO!

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend returning an HTTP 400 error, which means that "the request could not be understood by the server due to malformed syntax." ([RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-10.4.1))

Since you're expecting valid XML, you can load it into a [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/domdocument) using `loadXml` and use the result of `libxml_get_errors` to see the XML errors (I'd recommend using `libxml_use_internal_errors(true)` too).

You can return the libxml errors (e.g. "Unescaped '&' in request" etc) in the response body.